# How to find the bitrate of an mp3 file via command line?

Tags: command-line, mp3

What is the terminal command that can used to find the bitrate of an mp3 file?

Is there any other option available other than `mpg321 -t name.mp3`?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Simply put:

```
file song.mp3
```

> **Note:** `file` is included with Ubuntu.

---

For alias lovers, insert this at the end of your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
bitrate () {
    echo `basename "$1"`: `file "$1" | sed 's/.*, \(.*\)kbps.*/\1/' | tr -d " " ` kbps
}
```

Open a new Terminal window. You may now run the following command:

```
bitrate song.mp3
```

Comment: wow. Simple `file` command did the trick.

Comment: Be warned: if the file is variable bit rate (VBR), file will report only the one of the many bit rates present. (I think it's the first frame's bit rate.)  The answer could be deceptive if most of the file is at a very different rate.  If you want to know the average bit rate, see apacheuk's answer.

Comment: +1 Any chance you could add a brief summary to this answer, explaining how it works?

Comment: For some reason `file` doesn't work with a whole lot of MP3s I have which are properly identified by `exiftool` and even better by `mediainfo`.

Comment: Doesn't work for most of my files on Ubuntu 16.04.  As stated above, I'm pretty sure its due to file not understanding VBR files correctly.   "file" just says "Audio file with ID3 version 2.3.0"

Answer (score 52):

[MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/) is further solution to do that (not only on mp3).

```
sudo apt-get install mediainfo
```

Example:

```
mediainfo Aphrodite_-_Superman_\(dnb\).mp3 | grep "Bit rate"
```

Output:

```
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 192 Kbps
```

Another Example:

```
mediainfo Aphrodite_-_Superman_\(dnb\).mp3 | grep 'Bit rate  '
```

Another Output:

```
Bit rate                                 : 192 Kbps
```

Get exactly the audio bitrate via **mediainfo** in bps:

```
mediainfo --Output='Audio;%BitRate%' '/MY/MEDIA/FILE.MP3'
```

or in Kbps:

```
mediainfo --Output='Audio;%BitRate/String%' '/MY/MEDIA/FILE.MP3'
```

Comment: You could just specify `--Output=JSON` to get the output formatted as JSON. This is useful if you're using `mediainfo` inside another app.

Answer (score 28):

Install **mp3info** package

```
sudo apt-get install mp3info
```

To find the bitrate use

```
mp3info -r a -p "%f %r\n" *.mp3
```

will give the info you need, also has some other useful functions `man mp3info` for more info

Comment: mp3info does not support ID3v2 tagging.

Comment: @Ian: true as that may be, it's irrelevant to this question or this answer.

Comment: If you are curious about the bit rate alone, then yes -- it's irrelevant.  If you found this answer because you were working on a script that needed the bitrate in addition to other fields from your mp3 files (some of which only have ID3v2 tags) then this information would prevent you from going down a dead end with `mp3info` -- a program that does not always extract info from mp3s.

Answer (score 12):

You can install the package `libimage-exiftool-perl`:

```
sudo apt-get install libimage-exiftool-perl
```

Then run:

```
exiftool -AudioBitrate GoldLion.mp3
```

It will output something like:

```
Audio Bitrate : 192 kbps
```

Comment: Cool! This provides wonderful meta information about the file.

Comment: Yes but it doesn't identify VBR. Buzz-Dee's answer below about MediaInfo helps with that.

Answer (score 11):

The best info, by-far, is provided by `ffprobe` (part of the `ffmpeg` package). *mpg123* is also nice, but hard to grep output, which is probably why you were asking for something else.

```
$ mpg123 -t example.mp3 2>&1 | grep -A1 -E "^MPEG"
MPEG 2.5 L III cbr32 11025 mono

$ ffprobe example.mp3 2>&1 | grep Stream
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 11025 Hz, mono, s16p, 32 kb/s
```

For pro-use, do this:

```bsh
# ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams example.mp3

{
    "streams": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "codec_name": "mp3",
            "codec_long_name": "MP3 (MPEG audio layer 3)",
            "codec_type": "audio",
            "codec_time_base": "1/11025",
            "codec_tag_string": "[0][0][0][0]",
            "codec_tag": "0x0000",
            "sample_fmt": "s16p",
            "sample_rate": "11025",
            "channels": 1,
            "channel_layout": "mono",
            "bits_per_sample": 0,
            "r_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "avg_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "time_base": "1/14112000",
            "start_pts": 0,
            "start_time": "0.000000",
            "duration_ts": 55294344,
            "duration": "3.918250",
            "bit_rate": "32000",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 0,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0
            }
        }
    ],
    "format": {
        "filename": "example.mp3",
        "nb_streams": 1,
        "nb_programs": 0,
        "format_name": "mp3",
        "format_long_name": "MP2/3 (MPEG audio layer 2/3)",
        "start_time": "0.000000",
        "duration": "3.918250",
        "size": "17260",
        "bit_rate": "35240",
        "probe_score": 51,
        "tags": {
            "title": "Sound Effects - Female Operatic La 1 - Opera singer sings La.",
            "artist": "Download Sound Effects - SoundDogs - AOS",
            "album": "http://www.Sounddogs.com",
            "track": "0",
            "copyright": "(c) 2010 Sounddogs.com, All Rights Reserved",
            "genre": "SFX - Humans; Vocalizations",
            "comment": "Royalty Free Sound Effects - Sounddogs.com",
            "date": "2008"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is by far the best answer.

Comment: to verify a file is 320 kbps you would see `% ffprobe myfile.mp3 2>&1 |grep Stream
  Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 320 kb/s`